# how to make the click event disable on button in action Script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, nresponder

I have button i want to disable the click event on it when app loads and then enable the click event after some time how to do this

below is the my code for action script

```
        NResponder.addNative(controls.addCurrentBag, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOverCurrentBag);
        NResponder.addNative(controls.addCurrentBag, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOutCurrentBag);
        _currentBagClicked = NResponder.addNative(controls.addCurrentBag, MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickedCurrentBag);
        _currentBagClicked.paused = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
controls.addCurrentBag.mouseEnabled= false
```